# Solution to an apparently simple Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, trace, pseudoinverse

I'm stuck at a proof of a property that is stated in a paper. Imagine we have  a diagonal matrix $$\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1& &0\\ &\ddots&\\0&&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$$ with $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Consider the following optimization problem for $n\geq k$
\begin{align*}
\min_{A\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}}& tr(A\Sigma A^T)\\
s.t.\quad& AA^T = I_k
\end{align*}
The solution should be to choose the $k$ smallest values of $\lambda_i$ by orthonormal vectors in the matrix $A$ such that $tr(A\Sigma A^T)=\sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i$ if $\lambda_1\leq\ldots\leq \lambda_n$, but I don't know how to derive it.. it seems like a well known, simple problem, maybe there's a common trick to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Almost got it:
Assume w.l.o.g. that $\lambda_1\leq \ldots\leq \lambda_n$
\begin{align*}
tr(A\Sigma A^T)=tr((A\Sigma)^TA) =tr(\Sigma A^TA)
\end{align*}
The rank of $A^TA$ is exactly $k$, since $rank(A^TA)=rank(AA^T)=rank(I_k)$ and $A^TA$ is idempotent. Thus, there exist orthonormal basis transformation matrices (eigenvectors to the eigenvalues 1 and 0 form an orthonormal basis) $B\in\mathbb{R}^n$, such that
$$
B^T A^TA B=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_k&0\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and therefore it holds that
$$tr(\Sigma A^TA)=tr(\Sigma B^TA^TAB)=\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_k$$
But I'm not so sure about $tr(\Sigma A^TA)=tr(\Sigma B^TA^TAB)$, does anybody know why it holds?